# Swift UITableViewCell subclass, IBOutlet UILabel error, no error if used as normal var

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, xcode7

This is probably something really stupid, as I'm quite new to Swift and iOS development, but I have a `UITableView` and have subclassed `UITableViewCell` (call it `myCell`).

`myCell` has a `UILabel` *in the storyboard*, and I connected it to the code,     `@IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!` such that the little dot next to it is grey. Then in the initializer, `override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?)`, I get the following error upon accessing `myLabel` -- regardless of whether or not I instantiate it (`myLabel = UILabel()`) first or not:

`fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

**However**, if I declare `myLabel` as a standard `var`, `var myLabel: UILabel!`, and instantiate it as above in the initializer, things work.

If it matters, I have the `UITableView` in a `UIViewController` (as opposed to a `UITableViewController`), so the view controller implements `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate`, and adds the table view as a sub-view.

**My question is, why might `myLabel` be `nil` when working through the interface builder?** 
(I've checked the connection, and I've deleted the connection and created a new label -- both by ctrl+dragging from the storyboard `UILabel` to the code, and simply re-connecting by dragging from the circle in the code to the storyboard `UILabel`.)

**EDIT**

Calling my table cells via: 
`let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MyTableViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell` gives the following error:

`'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier MyTableViewCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'`

... which I don't understand, because "MyTableViewCell" is set as the reuseIdentifier for the cell prototype in the storyboard.

Comment: Yeah I've overridden both of those.

Comment: Did you create your viewcontroller instance from the storyboard scene?

Comment: Your outlets will be `nil` in your initialiser. You will have to wait until the view is loaded before setting their values.

Comment: Yeah it's attached to a tabBarController, which otherwise works properly.

Comment: If you declare a property as `weak` and the assign a UILabel to it without first having something hold a strong reference (such as by adding the label to the superview) then the label will imediately be released.  This is why you get the nil exception when you create the UILabel yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, there were two issues:

1) I didn't have an outlet (@IBOutlet) to the TableView in the ViewController subclass, and

2) I was using `let` to create a `UITableView` object in the ViewController's didLoad, and after setting the dataSource and delegate to `self`, was *adding it as a subview* to the ViewController's view, obviously screwing everything up.

If anyone else wants to do this, I found this link helpful:
https://medium.com/@ronm333/a-simple-table-view-example-in-swift-cbf9a405f975#.yymib1tm5

Thanks for the help, [rMickeyD](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5892739/rmickeyd).

Answer (score 1):

The UILabel in storyboard is connected to a specific cell with a specific reuseIdentifier.  Are you trying to access the label in a cell that is different than the one it is located in? This could cause the error you are having.

Comment: Yeah, it's a UILabel in the prototype cell in the storyboard, and the proper reuseIdentifier is (presumably) being passed -- actually its not -- see edit above.

Comment: Can you post your cellForRowAtIndexPath method?

Comment: Is your prototype cell registered as a UITableViewCell or specifically a MyTableViewCell?  It should be the latter.  Once this is done you will need to create a new file of MyTableViewCell.  This is where you would then connect your outlets.

Comment: It is -- I've got the prototype cell (Dynamic) registered as MyTableViewCell, with Identifier MyTableViewCell, and I have MyTableViewCell.swift with `class MyTableViewCell : UITableViewCell {`. Inside there is the outlet.

Comment: I think you can delete the init code.  You should not need that.  Also, I just saw you have a UITableView in a ViewController.  DId you connect your tableView delegate and datasource either in code or via storyboards?

Comment: if you mean, calling `tableView.delegate = self` and `tableView.dataSource = self` in the ViewController, then yes.

Comment: I need to see the full code to help more.  If you post your tableView methods in the viewController, the tableViewCell class and some screen shots of storyboards I can take a look.